# Navigation Component after back current destination not changed

Tags: android

I've 2 fragments, A & B
with action:

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_a_to_b"
            app:destination="@id/b"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popUpTo="@id/a"/>
```

after I move from a to b and pressing back,
and then try again to open b from a, the app crashes and the problem is that the navigation graph current destination remains fragment b instead of changing to a.

Update:
if fragment B inherit from Fragment class, it doesn't happen
if fragment B inherit from BottomSheetDialogFragment it does happen
any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i used the tag  instead of  in the navigation graph...

Comment: Hi Sharas, I am also facing the same issue. Please share your solution for this issue. Thanks